# Trouble with fonts when exporting a 2D-plot to vector formats

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format, fonts

I've set up my plot to look exactly how I like it. At least it does so on screen.
Upon export though, only the bitmap formats look the same.
For PDF and EPS, the FontSize seems to get ignored and the lines aren't outlined so when downscaling the whole plot the lines get thicker in relation.

Isn't there a simple way to just render the whole thing as a proper PDF with everything (including fonts) outlined and at correct size?!

EDIT:
So there were two different problems I ran into:
First was Adobe Illustrator somehow couldn't display all the text that Mathematica output into the PDF. Therefore the option to outline from within Mathematica is very convenient.

Second was my (newbish) mistake to specify the font size with `Scaled[0.02]` wich was clearly not what I wanted. I now changed it to fixed point sizes.

Comment: I think posting a self-contained minimal code example will be highly beneficial.

Comment: Mathematica uses different coordinates for plot items and fonts.  Plot items follow the plot coordinate system which scaled with the graphic.  Fonts are given in absolute physical size (points, centimetres) and don't scale by default.  These help achieve consistent font sizes across the document.  You probably scaled the graphic before exporting, but it's impossible to tell unless you give a working example that demonstrates the problem.  Also, please choose a proper and informative title (don't assume that it's broken just because it didn't work according to your expectations).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not knowing in what other external application you plan to process the exported `PDF`, I'm focusing mainly on the last paragraph of the question which asks for a way to outline fonts. To do this, you can simply define the function

```
outlinedExport[name_, gr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Export[name, 
  First@ImportString[ExportString[gr, "PDF"], "PDF", 
    "TextOutlines" -> True], FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Export]]]
```

Assuming your graphics object is `g`, you would do something like this:

```
outlinedExport["output.pdf", g, ImageSize -> 600]
```

This also works for other file formats, and accepts options such as `ImageSize`.

**Edit**

One additional *caveat* to watch out for: if your plot has a frame or axes that turn out to look too thin in the exported vector graphics, try adding options to your plot that explicitly fix the thickness, such as

```
AxesStyle->Thickness[.002]
```

or (if you have set `Frame -> True`:

```
FrameStyle -> Thickness[.002]
```

Answer (score 12):

*Mathematica* uses two differen sets of styles for displaying graphics on screen and for exporting: `ScreenStyleEnvironment` for displaying and exporting in raster formats and `PrintingStyleEnvironment` for printing and exporting to EPS and PDF formats (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124065/590388) for more details). One way to achieve consistent export to PostScript is to set `PrintingStyleEnvironment` the same as `ScreenStyleEnvironment`:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

See also [dedicated pitfalls answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137746/280).

Answer (score 4):

I've arrived at something that works for my scenario, though it's a bit hacky.

1. install the Mathematica Fonts on your system.
   On OS X they're in `Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Fonts/TrueType/MathematicaFonts.dfont`
   copy this file to `~/Library/Fonts`
   (To get inside the Mathematica.app bundle: right-click -> show package contents,
   to get to your Library, use "Go -> Go to Folder" in the Finder)
2. export plot as SVG
3. do a search & replace in the SVG (SVG is text after all), replacing 'Times' and 'SVGTimes' with 'Mathematica1'.
4. (optional) outline all strokes in your vector graphics application

Comment: This text replacement approach seems a little clunky - in particular if there are other fonts in the graphic that may cause problems. It would also be good to include an actual code example, and mention a specific `PDF` viewer application in which you observe the font size problem.