# How to preserve clipping when exporting a framed histogram with font embedding?

Tags: export, options, fonts, histograms

I work with histograms and would like to export it to EPS format. I've noticed that my exported image loses the PlotRangeClipping option that I set up when I export the plot. This is true for at least EPS, PNG and PDF.

Based on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/trouble-with-fonts-when-exporting-a-2d-plot-to-vector-formats) and its accepted answer, I defined the function

```
OutlinedExport[name_,gr_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
Export[
    name,
    First@ImportString[
        ExportString[
            gr,
            "PDF"
        ],
        "PDF",
        "TextOutlines"->True
    ],
    FilterRules[
        {opts},
        Options[Export]
    ]
]
```

Now here is an example of histogram

```
data = Table[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Random[]], {i, 1000}];
PlotB = Histogram[data, 20,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, Automatic},
    Frame->True]
OutlinedExport["output2.pdf", PlotB, ImageSize -> 600]
```

which appears to have lost the clipping during the export.

#### The questions are :

- Is there a way to preserve clipping as defined through options like PlotRangeClipping and PlotRangePadding ?
- If the problem is related with the OutlinedExport, is there a way to answer my question while also keeping the outline of fonts (which I need but have here removed for the sake of example) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is clearly a bug in `Import` with the `PDF` format, there can only be workarounds and compromise solutions. By exporting as in your own answer, you will retain the setting of `PlotRangeClipping` because at no point is it necessary to re-import the exported `PDF` to *Mathematica*. However, this way you almost certainly will run into missing font problems when importing the `PDF` (or `EPS`) into other graphics programs. For example, Adobe Illustrator and likewise Inkscape will be unable to display your graphic with the correct fonts in general.

I tried this with Inkscape and your exported file `test.pdf`, and it doesn't work properly.

So you *could* resort to finger-painting as in Mr.Wizard's answer where the clipped parts are hidden behind added rectangles, so that the result of `outlinedExport` look correct.

*Or* you could retreat to another approach which I [invented long ago](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#Mathematica2Illustrator), relying on an *external* program to convert fonts to outlines. That's what I used to do before *Mathematica* even had the ability to produce outlined fonts at all. The external dependence is [ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/).

If you want to go that route, here is an updated version of that procedure:

```
gsExport[exportName_, ob_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {device,
   printOption = First@Options[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment],
   out = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, 
      "MathematicaOutput" <> StringJoin[Map[ToString, DateList[]]] <> 
       ".pdf"}]
   },
  SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"];
  Export[
   out,
   ob,
   "PDF",
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Export]]
   ];
  SetOptions[$FrontEnd, printOption];
  device = 
   If[ToLowerCase[FileExtension[exportName]] == "eps", "epswrite", 
    "pdfwrite", "pdfwrite"];
  Run["gs -sDEVICE=" <> device <> " -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=" <> 
    exportName <> " -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE " <> out <> " -c quit"];
  DeleteFile[out]
  ]
```

It takes the export file name and the graphics object (`ob`) as the first two arguments, and also accepts additional options appropriate for `PDF` export. By default it exports to `PDF` with the provided name (`exportName`), but if you specify an en extension `.eps` you will get encapsulated postscript instead. The fonts are replaced y outlines by executing `gs` via `Run`. This assumes that `gs` is installed and in your system's executable `PATH`.

I thought this approach was obsolete by now, but apparently there are still enough bugs in *Mathematica* that open-source solutions must come to the rescue once again.

**Update:**

The above solution continues to work with `gs` version 9.16, but according to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775217/915703) (and thanks to Szabolcs for pointing it out) there is a new option that you could use in the future, if you encounter problems: replace `-dNOCACHE` by `-dNoOutputFonts`.

Comment: Nice alternative. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Since the clipping is lost, and I cannot find a way to make `Import`/`Export` retain it, I suggest adding it manually:

```
PlotC =
 Show[
  PlotB,
  Graphics[{White, Rectangle[Scaled[{-1, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}]], 
                   Rectangle[Scaled[{ 1, 0}], Scaled[{2, 1}]]}]
 ]

OutlinedExport["output4.pdf", PlotC, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works by drawing a white rectangle on either side of the plot range behind the frame labels (here shown in pink instead):

```
Show[PlotB, 
 Graphics[{LightRed, Rectangle[Scaled[{-1, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}]], 
                     Rectangle[Scaled[{ 1, 0}], Scaled[{2, 1}]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may need larger $x$ values inside `Scaled` to cover the full range, e.g.:

`Rectangle[Scaled[{-100, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}]]`

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem comes from the OutlinedExport function defined above which does not keep any clipping options. Fortunately, it seems possible to do without and keep the font embedding in the pdf.

The second answer from [the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/trouble-with-fonts-when-exporting-a-2d-plot-to-vector-formats) referred above actually answers this one too.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"];
data = Table[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Random[]], {i, 1000}];
PlotB = Histogram[data, 20, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, Automatic},
  FrameTicksStyle -> {
    Directive[
        Bold,
        FontFamily -> "Palatino Linotype",
        FontSize -> 14
        ],
    Directive[
        Bold,
        FontFamily -> "Palatino Linotype",
        FontSize -> 14
        ]
    },
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  ImagePadding -> {{80, 10}, {60, 5}},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.02],
  FrameLabel -> {
    Style[
        "blahblah",
        FontFamily -> "Palatino Linotype",
        FontSize -> 16
        ],
    Style[
        "blahblah",
        FontFamily -> "Palatino Linotype",
        FontSize -> 16]
    }]
Export["test.pdf", PlotB, ImageSize -> 600]
```

The function `Export` keeps then the font embedding as well as the `PlotRangeClipping`. It works for EPS, PDF,...

Comment: This does indeed work for exporting with embedded fonts as requested (+1). Interestingly though, if I now re-import that file using `Import["test.pdf"][[1]]`, the clipping is lost _again_! What this shows is that the problem is clearly with _Mathematica_'s `PDF` import. In my `outlinedExport` function which you were using, this must also be the place where things go wrong. I'll think about another workaround to that workaround..