# Exporting equations from Mathematica to Corel with full Latex quality

Tags: export, latex

I am wondering if there is any possible solution to exporting equations from *Mathematica* to *Corel*. I was trying first to export an equation as pdf from *Mathematica* and then to import .pdf to *Corel*, but many characters are missed. Maybe someone had success with this kind of problem.

Comment: Does it work if you use the function in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1286/245)? Just say `outlinedExport["output.pdf", g, ImageSize -> 600]` or something similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a similar problem with Adobe Illustrator, too. For that purpose, I use the following function (see [my web site](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#formulasToPDF) for more info):

```
toPDF[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  If[! ImageQ[x], 
   First@ImportString[
     ExportString[
      Pane[Style[TraditionalForm[HoldForm[x]], 
        FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Style]]], 
       FilterRules[{opts}, ImageSize], 
       BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
         Background -> (Background /. {opts} /. {Background -> 
              None})}], "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]];
SetAttributes[toPDF, HoldFirst]
```

Example:

```
toPDF[Integrate[1 + Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, Pi}], FontSize -> 18]
```

[image: screenshot]

Now you can either highlight the result (as I did above) and copy it as `PDF` (on Mac), or type `Export["eq.pdf", %]` in the next cell, to save to a file.

The reason I added the attribute `HoldAll` above is that I wanted to be able to export expressions like integrals without having them be evaluated. So the purpose of this function is really geared toward typesetting equations, and then copying them to Illustrator. Maybe this is also what you want for your drawing application.

I use `Pane` as a wrapper for the equation in order to be able to control the bounding box of the `PDF`. The function also accepts a `Background` option in case you want to add a color behind the equation.

**Edit for version 10.1:**

Due to added bugs in `Import` with `PDF` format, the example above won't work properly anymore. Another solution that still *does* work is the function `gsExport` [from my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9047/245). You have to make sure that `ghostscript` is installed and in the search path. If the linked code doesn't find your `gs` command, you could add the path directly in the code, as in `/path/to/gs`. After invoking `gsExport["filename.pdf", HoldForm[Integrate[1 + Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, Pi}]]]`, you can do `Import["filename.pdf"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much Jens. This I was trying to get. Quality of image-equation is very nice in corel. Thank you Jens a lot, hope that your "papers" look perfect.

Comment: Same problem with [BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88378/12) in v10.2.

Comment: Since v9.16, you can use the following with GhostScript: `gs -o out.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE-pdfwrite in.pdf`.  This won't involve any conversions to EPS.  It goes directly from PDF to PDF.

Comment: @Szabolcs Great, thanks, I'll add that to my linked answer! (I checked that the old syntax also still works in 9.16, though). I'll also have to file another bug report for the `Import` issue, I guess. Although I believe I reported stuff like that a couple of times already. New issues keep popping up...

Comment: @Szabolcs Reported the `Import` bug to Wolfram  [CASE:3391590].