# The space in default output of `ExportString` to Latex

Tags: latex

## Are there any reasons for converting subscriptbox to Tex with space?

---

```
ExportString[Subscript[\[Alpha], 1], "TeX"]

(*
    %% AMS-LaTeX Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com\documentclass{article}\u
sepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}\newcommand{\un
icode}[1]{{}}\newcounter{mathematicapage}\begin{document}\[\alpha _1\]\end{document}
*)
```

Of course, I can remove the space in via the option "BoxRules", and `$\alpha _1$` can also rendered well in SE.

But many people would edit my `$\alpha _1$` into `$\alpha_1$`, do you know whether there are any reasons for the default space generated by `ExportString`?

The same to other boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces in `LaTeX` export are harmless, but I think there is a valid reason to insert them after any control sequence such as `\alpha`: it is the easiest way to avoid creating undefined control sequences in situations where `\alpha` is followed by a variables name like `b` that is *not* itself a control sequence. Without spaces, this would be translated to `\alphab` which is obviously undefined.

This problem *only* arises at the end of control sequences, it's no problem when there are just a couple of variable names like `a b`. For them, it's permissible to leave out the space entirely and `LaTeX` will nevertheless treat each single letter as a separate variable. Therefore, `ExportString[Subscript[a b, 1], "TeX"]` doesn't insert any extra spaces after `b`. It only does it after symbols that translate to control sequences such as `\alpha`.

I'm by no means saying that *Mathematica's* space insertion trick is the *prettiest* way to export `LaTeX`, but it's an easy (or you might say lazy) solution.

Comment: But is there a way to override this space insertion, say, when exporting text infoprmation into pdf? For example, I have a string $a_{min,obs}$, which renders as $a_{min~,obs}$, which doesn't look good.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick The correct way to enter textual subscripts would be to enclose them in  quotation marks in the *Mathematica* expression. I.e., `"min"` etc. It gets translated to `\text{min}`, which is the right way to present multi-letter symbols in `LaTeX` (you should never simply write multi-letter names as plain characters in `LaTeX` because they're typeset as separate variables).

Comment: I should have been a bit more specific here, but I actually intend to export directly from Mathematica into pdf, not into latex however. The problem, though, is very similar to the one above. If I write Subscript["a", "min,obs"] and export it into pdf as part of a table, I get a string, which has an extra space after $min$.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick That's probably a completely different issue. You might try [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26303/245) instead.

Comment: The function toPDF gives the same space after min. I would think the problem is different, but it seems that extra spaces appear only after operator-like strings, like "min", or "circ" etc. Unlike in this question, however, it is not obvious, at each stage the extra spaces can be removed.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick I don't see this issue in PDF with Mathematica version 8. But if you can reproduce it, you could ask a new question.

Comment: Might very well be system-dependent, I added an example here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72896/extra-spaces-when-exporting-strings