# Exporting a histogram to PDF in without rasterising it

Tags: export, pdf-format

How can I export a histogram without rasterising it? The labels and axes seem unaffected, but the bars themselves are pixelated when I zoom into them in a PDF viewer.

For example, if I run

```
Export["~/test.pdf", Histogram@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000]];
```

I get a PDF that looks like this when zoomed in:

[image: Histogram]

This is a problem when I try to run it through `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf` (to work around some font problems when including the PDFs in a LaTeX document), since the whole image gets rasterised, including the text.

Comment: Did you see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1546/1356?

Comment: I think that might be opacity rather than rasterisation. At least, when you import the PDF, it comes in as lines (Opacity[0.595`]) not as an image...

Comment: @cormullion You're quite right. I now think converting to PostScript is entirely the wrong thing to do. All I *really* want is to convert the text into vector shapes, so that the fonts don't cause problems.

Comment: Perhaps this is of interest: [How to preserve clipping when exporting a framed histogram with font embedding?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8765/245). But the problem shown in your screenshot is due to `Opacity`, as @cormullion notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exported histogram bars are partially transparent and therefore look ugly where they overlap in the exported `PDF`. This seems to be a bug because it doesn't correspond to what the plot looks like in the Notebook.

To fix this particular problem, you just have to specify a line style directive forr the bars explicitly. Then you still get the reduced opacity when hovering over the bar in the Notebook display, but not in the exported `PDF`:

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000], 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Black]]]
```

Comment: Thanks – this more-or-less fixes the issue! Without the opacity in the edges, I can pass the PDFs through GhostScript without rasterising them. I still get problems if I try to plot more than one dataset, but I guess I'll just have to find a way of doing it without GhostScript.