# Import text outlines from PDF format properly

Tags: bugs, import, pdf-format, character-encoding, unicode

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 12.0**

---

I am attempting to implement this: [How can I wrap text around a circle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/how-can-i-wrap-text-around-a-circle/5732#5732)

But I need Unicode support.
Unfortunately, in my case, this gives a broken output (some Unicode characters missing replaced by rectangles)

```
ImportString[ExportString[
Style["ěščřžýáíé", FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
 FontSize -> 12],
"PDF"
],
"TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1]] // Graphics
```

[image: screenshot]

Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: The characters which do not work ( \[SHacek] and \[ZHacek ) are from ISOLatin2. So it looks like ISOLatin2 characters are not fully implemented when exporting them. I think this is just another bug and you should report it to Wolfram Research (support@wolfram.com) and then in a couple of days, or weeks, or months, or years, or never, it might get fixed in a future release.

Comment: It works as expected with versions 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 but fails starting from version 10.0. So it is a bug introduced in 10.0, adding the tag. Please report it to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: The bug seems to be in importing rather than exporting. When I export and save to file, then display the file with another software, it displays OK.

Comment: The bug has been reported and I got a confirmation e-mail acknowledging the bug.

Comment: Update: The error persist in 11.3.

Answer (score 6):

I reproduce the problem with versions 10.0.1, 10.4.1 and 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64. The problem isn't related to the font used: the same happens when instead of `FontFamily -> "Verdana"` I set `"Times"` or `"Courier"`. At the same time, with versions 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 I get the expected output:

[image: screenshot]

Note that in versions 8 and 9 non-ASCII characters are `Export`ed as outlines, not as text. This is the reason why they are always imported as outlines, even with `"TextOutlines" -> False`.

The new `Export` produces a correct PDF file:

```
Export["test.pdf", 
  Style["ěščřžýáíé", FontFamily -> "Courier", FontSize -> 12]] // SystemOpen
```

Here is how it is rendered by Acrobat 11 (I intentionally selected a part of text to show that it is selectable text):

[image]

The text can be copied and pasted from Acrobat into Notepad correctly, hence there are no problems with encoding in the exported PDF.

This file (created by version 11.2.0) can't be correctly imported by pre-10 `Import`: the latter is unable to decode correctly any character at all:

[image: screenshot]

So the overall conclusion is that both `Import` and `Export` starting from version 10 received Unicode support, but in the case of `Import` there are bugs with some particular symbols.

Unfortunately I can't suggest any workaround for this problem except downgrading to a pre-10 version of *Mathematica*. Even new in version 10 `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` function is affected by this bug:

[image: screenshot]

Apart of this, the options `"TextMode" -> "Outlines"` and `"TextOutlines" -> True` are ignored by `Export`, so we can't revert to the old behavior of `Export`.

Please report it to the tech support.

---

#### UPDATE

According to discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26303/280), one can use GhostScript for outlining fonts in the exported PDF file. It can be automatized with `gsExport` function from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9047/280) answer by [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens). Then `Import` will correctly import outlines from obtained PDF file (like it was in versions 8 and 9).

Answer (score 2):

It works with Times on my system (Mac 10.11.6, Mathematica 11.1.1):

```
ImportString[ExportString[
  Style["ěščřžýáíé", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12], "PDF"],
  "TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1]] // Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: Which version do you use and on which OS? It doesn't work for me with versions 10.0.1, 10.4.1 and 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Does not work for me. Linux, Mathematica 11.2

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I should have said that this is on a Mac with OS  10.11.6 and Mathematica 11.11.1.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Works for me also (with OSX 10.11.6, mma 11.2) with Times but not Times New Roman,  with Courier but not Courier New, with Helvetica but not Arial, ... `(Print@{#, 
     ImportString[
        ExportString[
         Style["ěščřžýáíé", FontFamily -> #, FontSize -> 12], "PDF"], 
        "TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1]] // 
      Graphics}) & /@ $FontFamilies[[1 ;;]]` (be careful, this completely crashes my mma session when it reaches the font "YuGothic" (ExportString[.., "PDF"]) ...).