# ExportString "PDF" crashes FrontEnd session

Tags: front-end, export, pdf-format, fonts, crash

While doing some general tests with [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163659/19960), it appears that this simple command crashes my whole *Mathematica* session (*Mathematica* 11.2.0, OSX 10.11.6):

```
ExportString[Style["hello", FontFamily -> "YuGothic", FontSize -> 12], "PDF"]
```

It seems only to concern this ("YuGothic") particular OSX font and "PDF" export ...

Comment: Does it crash the Kernel only or the whole session including FrontEnd?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It crashes the whole session Kernel+FE !

Comment: It is best to report this to the support. BTW, your code `(Print@{#, ImportString[ ExportString[ Style["ěščřžýáíé", FontFamily -> #, FontSize -> 12], "PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"][[1, 1]] // Graphics}) & /@ $FontFamilies[[1 ;;]]` doesn't crash FrontEnd v.11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64, so it is seemingly an OS-related problem.

Comment: You are not the only one who faces the FE crash on OS X: [earlier report](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89022/custom-fonts-show-as-boxes-when-opening-mathematica-made-pdfs-with-illustrator/91669#comment248835_89088).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov it seems to be a double - OSX & font -  specific problem ... clearly a "minor" problem