# How can I get vectorized text when exporting to pdf?

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

Consider this code:

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/3}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/3}];
p1 = Graphics[Raster[data], Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Large, 
  ImageSize -> 300];
p2 = ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Large, 
  ImageSize -> 300];
Export["~/Downloads/1.pdf", p1, ImageResolution -> 100]
Export["~/Downloads/2.pdf", p2, ImageResolution -> 100]
```

Why does the font in the first plot appear vectorized while the the font in the second does not?

[image]
[image]

*Update*:

remove the ImageResolution option will vectorize both plots, but ImageResolution is very helpful in reducing the pdf file size and I can't give up on that.

```
Export["~/Downloads/1.pdf", p1]
Export["~/Downloads/2.pdf", p2]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is not an answer, but [the same thing happens](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7396898/758485) when exporting these graphics as EMF or WMF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/trouble-with-fonts-when-exporting-a-2d-plot-to-vector-formats).

Comment: version or system issue? I get vectors in both cases w/v9 on windows.

Comment: By the way, exporting to EPS i see in both cases the entire file is 'vector', i.e. each square is drawn and filled.  You might try exporting eps and converting externally.

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer to the question in the title, "How can I get vectorized text when exporting to pdf?" is the same as what I suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18631/245):

```
rasterTrick[plot_] := 
 Show[plot, 
  Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]

Export["~/Downloads/1.pdf", p1 // rasterTrick]
```

The function `rasterTrick` is described in the linked answer, and you'll notice that the white lines between the exported gray squares are gone. The density plot has been turned into a bitmap at high resolution, but the frame labels are **not rasterized**.

So the `Export` command just needs to be augmented by `//rasterTrick`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem seems to be the ImageResolution options. Only use Export["~/Downloads/2.pdf", p2], the frame labels are also not rasterized.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But your *reason* for adding `ImageResolution` is to get a better quality density plot, without the white lines, right? I see no other reason to use `ImageResolution` in the first place. My trick achieves this improvement in quality, as if you had used `ImageResolution -> 200`, but it applies rasterization only to the plot contents and not to the axes or frames. It's a hack that I discovered by accident, but it's better than `ImageResolution` here.