# Display error on frame label after exporting image to pdf

Tags: output-formatting

This is a simple plot, it looks fine in Mathematica. But after exporting it to pdf file, the display of vertical frame label has an error. The "33" in the subscript "epsilon33" becomes somewhat a superscript. It appears this error only occurs on vertical label with Greek letter as subscript. Assume the following simple plot

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(\[Epsilon]33\)]\)", 20], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(\[Epsilon]33\)]\)", 20]
 }]
```

(Note that the `Style` is not related and is only for making the bug better visible)

This is the plot in Mathematica

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In the exported pdf file, the label on the y-axis (and we should emphasis that it is only this vertical label!) of the frame has somehow turned the "33" into a superscript:

> [image]

I use 10.0 version on Window 7 system and halirutan can confirm this behaviour on Mac OS X with Mathematica 10.0.2.

Comment: Is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66788/greek-letters-do-not-export-correctly/66789#66789)  Helpful?

Comment: I have simplified the example of your code. Now there is a greater chance someone comes up with an explanation.

Comment: Another finding: If you use `Rotate[Style["\!\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(\[Epsilon]33\)]\)", 20],Pi/2]` as x-label, the subscript is destroyed as well. And when you use a normal character like `b` instead of epsilon, it works.

Comment: Same on _Linux_ 10.0.1. Works fine on v8.0.4.

Comment: There were some posts a couple of weeks ago about bugs in V10 with left frame labels.

Comment: I tried 8.0 version on Windows 7 and worked fine. This looks like a bug for 10.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

I originally developed [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX) to deal with various similar formatting issues. What pushed me over the line was noticing how exporting to PDF sometimes changes the formatting. While many of these issues have been fixed or improved since then (and since your post), I would still recommend MaTeX to achieve high-quality formatting that is guaranteed not to change upon export.