# How can I export 3D plots as vector graphics?

Tags: plotting, export, graphics3d, pdf-format, version-10.3

Consider the following simple example code:

```
plot3D = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, Mesh -> All];
Export["plot3D.pdf", plot3D]
```

As clearly seen, the output is *not* a vector graphics.

How can I export a 3D image into a vector graphics?

---

## Second edit:

#### Workaround given in [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100312/27539) to linked question

## First edit

Unfortunately, the solutions proposed in the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/27539), do not really work.
For example consider the following plot, as shown inside Mathematica (code on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/glS512/c3f3b0734714003ead10)):
[image]

This plot is built entirely using Graphics3D primitives, if that matters, so it should be relatively easy to export as vector graphics (I guess).

Exporting it directly with `Export["out.pdf",plot]` produces a rasterized output.

Using the second solution of Jens in the linked answer, i.e.:

```
Export["out.pdf",Graphics[Inset[plot, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]]
```

produces the following (obviously not right) vector graphics:

[image]

The other solution of directly printing into pdf does not work either: using the default Windows 10 pdf printer gives a rasterized image, while printing with the Foxit Reader Pdf printer gives the following truncated image:

[image]

So, aren't there other solutions to obtain a vector graphics with Mathematica?

Comment: try "svg" https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/SVG.html

Comment: @Nasser just tried. The output does not seem to be a vector graphics, and the quality is even worse than with pdf.

Comment: When I exported it as svg, and looked at the .svg file using editor, I see Mathematica is actually making .png image inside and just encoding the image data. Here is the line: `<image id="image83" width="360" height="287" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR.....`  so it looks like Mathematica does not really support true svg. It just wraps the png encoded data inside an svg file!

Comment: I tried the same thing with 2D plot, and now it is true svg format (vector graphics). So it seems Mathematica does not really support true svg with 3D. Only 2D type plots? For 3D it uses png data and just puts it inside svg file (same with pdf, it puts endcoded png image data inside pdf)

Comment: @Nasser that is indeed what you also see by exporting into pdf. Exporting 2D plots results in clearly vector graphics object, exporting 3D plots does not. My question is therefore if there is a way around this problem, eventually (but preferably not) using some external tools.

Comment: May be this was done as temporary solution until WRI adds true vector graphics export to 3D plots. May be in version 11 it will do true svg for 3D.

Comment: Why don't you export it as an EPS `Export["plot3D.eps", plot3D,"EPS"]`?

Comment: You can do it with `Export["123.pdf", plot3D, "AllowRasterization" -> False]`. However it was broken after v10.0. Also related: [(6301676)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301676) on SO and [(1542)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542).

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z exporting to EPS produces a vector graphics, but it also produces strange mesh-like artifacts

Comment: Response to the "EDIT" section: 1) Please read [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8415/280) about why you get different font sizes and slightly different styles in `Export`ed PDF than inside of the Notebook. 2) Please provide code for your figure in order to allow us to check the solutions. <continued in the next comment>

Comment: <continued from previous comment> 3) I have checked both `Export`ing to EPS and the `Inset` workaround with the following plot and found that the produced EPS and PDF files are simply incorrect, so obviously they broken exporting `Graphics3D` into EPS and PDF in version 10 (it is a bug): `ListPointPlot3D[Table[Table[(4Pi-t){Cos[t+s Pi/2],Sin[t+s Pi/2],0}+{0,0,2t},{t,0,4Pi,.1}],{s,4}],Filling->Bottom,ColorFunction->"Rainbow",BoxRatios->Automatic,FillingStyle->Directive[LightGreen,Thick,Opacity[.1]],AxesLabel->{"a","n"}]`. With version 8.0.4 I obtain the correct PDF file but incorrect EPS file.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I added the code on a gist and provided the [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/594c165b333c41e9c5a1) in question

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I just randomly found out something *really* odd. I have two plots like the one posted above. If I export them singularly into pdf, I get rasterized images. But if I export the two plots combined with `GraphicsRow`, ***the output is now a vector graphics perfectly formatted***. I really didn't expect this. Can you replicate this behaviour?

Comment: @glS 1) Your linked code contains undefined symbols and produces error messages instead of the plot when I evaluate it. Please correct the code. 2) When you wrap your `Graphics3D` by `GraphicsRow` you produce `Graphics` with `Inset` containing the original `Graphics3D`. So this method is identical to the `Inset` workaround and differs only in parameters of `Inset`. I recommend my [`shortInputForm`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function for investigation of the internal structure of graphics.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov sorry about that, I must have checked the code without quitting the kernel first, try the link in the edited answer, it should work now. I will investigate with the proposed method, as it seems that properly tweaking the options of `Inset` produces the wanted result

Comment: I have reproduced your result. The key is addition of the option `ImageSize -> 1000` in `GraphicsRow`. The same result can be achieved with `Graphics[Inset[pl], ImageSize -> 1000]` (where `pl` is your plot).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov yes, I also just found out that `Export`ing `GraphicsRow[{plot}, ImageSize -> whatever]` instead of simply `plot` works like a charm. I can post this as an answer/workaround if you want (and allow me)

Comment: I cannot reopen this question by oneself and the usual recommendation in such situations is to post new solution in the linked duplicate thread. This allows us to have all solutions in one place instead of having them sprayed over many threads.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov it makes sense of course. I'll do that, thanks for your help.