# Is there a way to export a 3D contour plot (contour lines only) to a vector format?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, export

I have a function defined on a 3D surface, which I wish to plot as a contour plot, and export to a vector graphics format. Based on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100156/how-can-i-export-3d-plots-as-vector-graphics?noredirect=1&lq=1) and various others, it seems that there is generically no way to do this for 3D plots (unless something has been introduced since v10). I tried RegionPlot and ParametricPlot3D with MeshFunctions, etc, but they all export raster graphics.

However, is there some hack to make it work for a function where I only wish to export the contour lines themselves (i.e. no shading or gradients) on the surface of a sphere? In 2D, it's possible to nicely simplify the plotted lines as in the solutions to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill/3196#3196), so can something like this somehow be generalised to lines on the surface of a sphere? Or is it strictly only 2D graphics that are supported for vector output?

---

**Edit**

A (simplified) example of the sort of plot I mean:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
  Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r} |-> 
    Sin[2 \[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]]}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], 
 MeshStyle -> Thickness[Medium]]
```

[image: contour lines on a sphere]

Comment: Contour surfaces or contour lines? An example showing something to be exported would help.

Comment: just the contour lines, over a simple 3D surface

Comment: Yes, now we can only use Mathematica 9.0 to export 2D vector format pdf  file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or project to 2D plane and export to 2D vector format pdf.

```
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
    Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 
    0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
   MeshFunctions -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
     Sin[2 θ] Cos[ϕ]], PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], 
   MeshStyle -> Thickness[Medium], PlotPoints -> 80, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, Axes -> False, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic",
    ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False];
twodimplot = 
  Graphics[
   plot[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} -> 
     Most[RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}] . {x, y, z}]];
Export["test.pdf", twodimplot]
SystemOpen["test.pdf"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is a `Tube` okay?

```
foo = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
   Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r} |-> 
     Sin[2 \[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]]}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  MeshStyle -> Tube[0.02]]
Export["/tmp/foo.svg", foo]
```

[image]