# Vectorizing in 3D environments

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, export, pdf-format, antialiasing

The following code

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/2}, {Cos[t + Pi], Sin[t + Pi], t/2}, If[
   EvenQ[Floor[4 t/Pi]], {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/2}, {Cos[t + Pi], 
    Sin[t + Pi], t/2}]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}, ViewVertical -> {0, -1, 0}, 
 Axes -> False]
```

yields

[image]

I want to export this as a vectorized image. However, when I save it as either PDF or SVG, I get some antialiasing artifacts. For example, zooming in,

[image]

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by **when I save it as either PDF or SVG**? Did you use the `Export` command? Please show all code used, not word description.

Comment: I mean exactly that, by right-clicking on the image and saving the graphic as a PDF. Running `Export["img.pdf", img]`, where `img` is the object in the code, yields the same result.

Comment: See some related issue on this. For example [exporting-graphics-for-publications-how-to-achieve-consistent-line-thicknesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931479/exporting-graphics-for-publications-how-to-achieve-consistent-line-thicknesses)  I see same thing on windows 10 after exporting to pdf.

Comment: I am wondering if this is related to the 3D environment, and if I should somehow project the object onto a 2D plane before exporting it. For example, doing `Export["img.pdf", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]` causes no issue, as expected. [See this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139050/converting-3d-graphics-to-2d-for-better-export)

Comment: I think the math problem that leads to a coding problem that is solved by rasterization is this: When two objects cross in front of each other in a 3d view, you have to break them up and draw the part in front in 3d on top in 2d. This problem has long been solve via rasterization. Perhaps breaking up polygons/line into pieces that intersect only at boundaries has been solved (seems solvable, if not quickly), but that seems what is needed in general. For the problem at hand or any monochrome line figure, in-front/behind doesn't matter. Do you want a solution just for this problem or in general?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The general solution would be interesting and yes, I agree the rasterization problem is solved. However, as mentioned in my "answer", I think converting the precise mathematical description of the specific functions I use within `ParametricPlot3D` in the projected view should be possible via the `ViewPoint` options, directly. It would be really interesting to have that done automatically, for any setting configuration, and even, perhaps, combine it with rasterization to address other general 3D plots (like `Plot3D` or `RegionPlot3D`).

Comment: That way, we would have an analytical solution for many cases, provided they are mathematically "describable", and avoiding, to some extent, the use of geometrical primitives.

Comment: I think the following Q&A shows how to get the projection matrix: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d, if it's any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- replace `ViewPoint -> {Infinity, 0, 0}` to `ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 0},  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"`

```
plot3 = ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/2}, {Cos[t + Pi], 
    Sin[t + Pi], t/2}, 
   If[EvenQ[Floor[4 t/Pi]], {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/2}, {Cos[t + Pi], 
     Sin[t + Pi], t/2}]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 0}, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewVertical -> {0, -1, 0}, 
  Axes -> False]
```

- the same way as my previous answer to get a vector format pdf.
  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275712/72111

```
plot2 = Graphics[plot3[[1]] /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {z, y}]
Export["test.pdf", plot2]
SystemOpen["test.pdf"]
```

[image]

Comment: Fascinating approach! Just out of curiosity, in your other answer, `PlotPoints` does define "smoothness", to some extent, right?

Comment: @samwolfe Yes,` PlotPoints -> 80, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4` make the curve smooth.

Comment: Great. This is more than enough, naturally, but I wonder if there is a systematic way to incorporate the analytical projected curves within Mathematica (for monochrome line figures, at least) so that we could plot the actual 2D curves from mathematical expressions. Perhaps I could write a question focussing on that alone. Either way, great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but a solution to my particular problem:

```
helix1[t_] := {Sin[t], t/2}
helix2[t_] := {Sin[t + Pi], t/2}
connectingLine[t_] := 
 If[EvenQ[Floor[4 t/Pi]], {Sin[t], t/2}, {Sin[t + Pi], t/2}]
img = Rotate[
  ParametricPlot[{helix1[t], helix2[t], connectingLine[t]}, {t, 0, 
    4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black, Axes -> False], Pi/2]
Export["img.pdf", img]
```

[image]

This produces a `Graphics` object which I can easily export as a vector, without the antialiasing issue.

The general question is somewhat trickier, as it has to do with how Mathematica handles the export of `Graphics3D` objects. Ultimately, my "solution" is merely analytical, where a projection onto a 2D plane is relatively easy, given the `ViewPoint` setting in the original `ParametricPlot3D`. This has already been partially discussed before in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139050/converting-3d-graphics-to-2d-for-better-export), and it would be interesting to know whether there is a reasonably general way of guaranteeing lossless vectorized images from 2D representations of 3D plots.

I am not too familiar with vector graphics rendering, but it would be interesting to know whether this has been discussed before within Mathematica. In particular, whether `ViewPoint` settings alone could be used to directly infer the 2D projection, rather than merely using standard vectorizing techniques, where information would be lose.