# Correctly labeling plot axes

Tags: plotting, formatting, labeling

I need to have those writing on my $Y$ axis and $X$ axis:

$$\frac{\text{d} \Psi_{\nu}}{\text{d}t}$$
for what concerns the $Y$ axis, and a trivial $t$ on the $X$ axis.

Clearly I know how to write $t$.

What I cannot do is the derivative symbol.

Also, once I wrote the label, it is not saved not the original figure.

For example, this is my code for the moment:

```
Labeled[
  Plot[
    {Gamma[1.25]*(1 - MittagLefflerE[0.25, 1, -z^(0.25)])/(z^(0.25)), 
     Gamma[1.5]*(1 - MittagLefflerE[0.5, 1, -z^(0.5)])/(z^(0.5)), 
     Gamma[1.75]*(1 - MittagLefflerE[0.75, 1, -z^(0.75)])/(z^(0.75)), 
     Gamma[2]*(1 - MittagLefflerE[1, 1, -z])/(z)}, {z, 0, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> 
      {{Black, Bold}, {Black, Dotted, Bold}, 
       {Black, Dashed, Bold}, {Black, DotDashed, Bold}}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"", ""}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}], 
  {t, Subscript[ψ', ν]}, {Bottom, Left}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

But when I am going to save the file.eps, non of the label are present. The writings are disappeared. How to solve this?

Comment: These may help: [(736)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/736/121), [(15884)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15884/121),

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question I believe a combination of [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) should work for you, e.g.

```
TraditionalForm[HoldForm[D[Subscript[ψ, ν], t]]]
```

[image]

At the moment I am unable to replicate the export-to-EPS problem but I am sure I have seen other questions regarding problems with EPS.

Comment: @AlanTuring I am glad I could help.  What version of *Mathematica* and what platform are you using?  I am trying to find a relevant Q&A for the export issue.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot: It's Mathematica 10.0.2.0 for Mac OS X

Comment: @AlanTuring Please try the function provided in this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8413/121

Comment: You're very nice, but frankly I understood nothing about the other part, from those answers. And I gave up, because it's really impossible that a super cool software like Mathematica couldn't have ANY SIMPLE IMPLEMENTATION for the labeling. It's unbelievable.

Comment: @AlanTuring In that case I am sorry I couldn't be more helpful.  I consider my answer here a sufficiently simple implementation, but *Mathematica* lacks publication quality typesetting which is why I linked to the $\LaTeX$ Q&A's as I believe that is how most people handle that deficiency.  As for export to EPS failing I think that is a bug or *possibly* a system configuration issue (fonts?) and I would still like to try to help you resolve that if you have the interest.