# Problems with nonalphanumeric characters when exporting to PDF/SVG on Mma 12

Tags: export, pdf-format, version-12, svg-format

It seems that exporting cells containing nonalphanumeric characters to SVG or PDF formats doesn't work as it should in Mma 12 on Linux (Fedora 30). For example

```
ImportString[ExportString[Cell["Why this? Test 1234!+=*", "Text"], "PDF"], "PDF"]
```

generates

```
Import::general: Unknown font type /CIDFontType0
```

[image]

and creates a garbled PDF file. With

```
Export["test.svg", Cell["Why this? Test 1234!+=*", "Text"]]
```

I equally get a weird-looking SVG file

[image]

All the tricks described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/trouble-with-fonts-when-exporting-a-2d-plot-to-vector-formats) do not seem to make any difference.

Mmm 11.3 and older versions are not affected. I *suppose* that Windows and macOS versions of Mma 12 are also not affected, since that would come out much earlier, but I didn't check explicitly

Can someone confirm this behavior of Mma 12 on Linux?

Comment: I do not reproduce this problem with 64bit version 12.0.0 on Linux Ubuntu 19.0.4.

Comment: Interesting. I reported this to WRI and it was acknowledged by them as a bug. @Szabolcs also told me that this is a long-standing issue and one can use Ghostscript as a workaround (https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX/blob/a5011ecb2a6b56a1399b8f986be348993fcaf50b/MaTeX/MaTeX.m#L494)
Now I wonder why with Ubuntu it just works...